# how can we we replicate a user experience of a e-commerce application with multiple images without loading images?

Tags: jmeter-3.2

1.Through jmeter recorded the script with out images.
2.Run the script by keeping 10 users.
3.Jmeter will show the execution and response time.

But how can we justify and show evidence to top level managemnt that even though with out capturing images the application response time is same as live user experience.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand, and perhaps the title is misleading? Are you asking how to prove the effectiveness of your method, or are you asking how to do it?

Comment: Actually my question is,how can we prove that application response time/page load response time is same as end user actions. i,e we record and run the script with out capturing images in ecommerece application..But end user will see all the images.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the two directly is not an apples-to-apples comparison, because they measure different things. Actually, Load Tester measures a lot of the same things for each, but what is generally considered the most important metric – Page Duration – is actually measuring a different aspect of performance in each case.

**Virtual Browsers:**
Virtual Browsers work at the HTTP layer – they send the same HTTP messages to the server that real browsers would send. The Page Duration measures the time from the beginning of the first request that is sent to the server to the end of the last response for a resource on that page.
Our Virtual Browsers(JMeter) will use the same number of connections to the server as a real browser. And it will distribute the requests amongst those connections in a very similar way: it will use inactive connections first, connections remain open for a while, etc. When done correctly, the target application cannot tell the difference between our Virtual Browser and a human operating a real browser.

**Real Browsers:**
well, REAL browsers that are driven by our virtual user instead of a human user. The driving takes place via APIs into the browser that are designed for automation (Eg : JMeter Selenium Web Driver)
For example, a Go To URL step instructs the browser to navigate to a URL. The Duration of that step measures from the time the command is sent to the browser until the browser reports completion (or failure). In the case of the Go To URL command, the command is complete when the browser fires the “On Load” event. This step will include the amount of time to get all the resources from the server – which is what is measured by the Virtual Browsers. It will ALSO include the amount of time the browser takes to render the page on the screen, which is not measured by the Virtual Browsers (since they never render the page).

Answer (score 0):

- The better way to do it would be to check the option "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" in: Thread Group Right Click -> Sampler -> HTTP Request -> Advanced -> Retrieve All Embedded Resources so all resources all loaded.

If you don't want to measure the embedded resources response times, for example if you are using a CDN or 3rd parties, you can use a "View Results Table" and enable the option "Child samples". This way you can see the response time from the main requests and from the embedded resources separately.

The issue is, secondary requests are made in parallel threads, so the sum of the response times is larger than the response time registered by the Transaction Controller. To avoid this you can select the option "Parallel downloads. Number", next to "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" in "HTTP Request" and enter the number of "parallel downloads".

Moreover you may link to follow blog :
https://www.redline13.com/blog/